# I commited to master locally, then branched and added more commits. How can I remove the first commit on master?

Tags: git

I did the following operations on my git repo:

1. did commit A on master locally
2. created MyBranch locally
3. did commit B on MyBranch locally
4. did commit C on MyBranch locally

I intended for commit A to occur on MyBranch, not master. In addition commit A's changes are no longer needed, and were reverted in commit C.

Can I remove commit A completely, or move commit A to MyBranch, while at the same time preserving the branch, as well as commit B and C?

Comment: Reset your master branch to the commit before A. Then rebase `-i` (interactive) your branch off master and delete the commits you don't want

Comment: I usually use a [shell function](https://gist.github.com/nickodell/6a936630b30f664793615c5dc4cfa78d) I wrote which overwrites my current state on a branch with the origin remote's state for that branch. I like to do it this way because it avoids a multi-step process, but the downside is that it can lose local data because it directly manipulates branches using `update-ref`.

Comment: Side note: Commit A *is* on MyBranch. It just so happens, that it is *also* on master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your local version of master.

`git branch -D master`

Then check it out again.

(This is assuming that master exists remotely in the state you wish for)

---

If master doesn't exist in the state you wish for remotely then use a hard git reset.

`git switch master`
`git reset --hard HEAD^`